# Assets\scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(41,10): error CS0161: 'PlayerMovement.IsGrounded()': not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have recently start this and facing this error

Assets\scripts\PlayerMovement.cs(41,10): error CS0161: 'PlayerMovement.IsGrounded()': not all code paths return a value
Here is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
Rigidbody rb;
[SerializeField] float movementSpeed = 6f;
[SerializeField] float jumpForce = 5f;

[SerializeField] Transform groundCheck;

[SerializeField] LayerMask ground;

// Start is called before the first frame update

void Start()
{
Debug.Log("Hello from Start");
rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();

}

// Update is called once per frame

void Update()
{
float horizontalInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
float verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

rb.velocity = new Vector3(horizontalInput * movementSpeed, rb.velocity.y, verticalInput * movementSpeed);


if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") /*&& IsGrounded()*/)
{
rb.velocity = new Vector3(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce, rb.velocity.z);
}

}

bool IsGrounded()
{
Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, .1f, ground);
}
}
```

Why is it happening please let me know about it, Thankyou.

Comment: Please don't tag the `[unityscript]` scripting language for questions about the C# programming language. Likewise, questions about bugs in your code should not be tagged with `[visual-studio]` as they are not questions about how to use the Visual Studio application.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your IsGrounded() function.

You have to return a value **true or false** from it.

So for your function:

```
bool IsGrounded()
{
    return Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, .1f, ground);
}
```

Comment: bool IsGrounded()
{
return true;
}

Comment: You don't have to return true because your Physics.CheckSphere should return true or false.